# const fs = require("fs") not working correctly on Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, require

This is my first post here so i apologise if i make an error.

I am having an problem when trying to use const fs = require("fs") in Node js. Visual Studio code IDE is not recognising it as being assigned and when i try to use fs.writeFile i am getting an error.

I have already tried looking online but can not find any solution. I am new to coding and would appreciate some help on this.

```
const http = require("http");
const fs = require("fs");

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  const url= req.url;

  const method = req.method;
  if (url === "/") {
    res.write("<html>");
    res.write("<head><title>Enter Message</title></head>");
    res.write("<body><form action='/message' method='POST'><input type='text' name='message'><button type='submit'>Enter</button></input></form>");
    res.write("</html>");
    return res.end();
  }
  if (url === "/message" && method === "POST") {
    fs.writeFile("message.txt", "DUMMY");
  }
  res.setHeader("content-type", "text/html");
  res.write("<html>");
  res.write("<head><title>My First Page</title></head>");
  res.write("<body><h1>Hello From My Node Js Server!!!!</h1></body>");
  res.write("<html>");
});
```

I expected the dummy text to be written to the file when i ran the program but i just get the following error.

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: Callback must be a function
    at maybeCallback (fs.js:128:9)
    at Object.writeFile (fs.js:1158:14)
    at Server.http.createServer (C:\Users\garry\Documents\Eloquent Javascript\Practice\practice.js:15:8)
    at Server.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at parserOnIncoming (_http_server.js:676:12)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:109:17)
```

Answer (score 4):

According to the Node.js documentation, you must provide a callback function to `fs.writeFile`.

Reference: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback

fs.writeFile is asynchronous so you need a callback function as mentioned in documentation or you can use [fs.writeFileSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options)

Answer (score 1):

The method signature for `writeFile` is, `fs.writeFile(file, data[, options], callback)` meaning it expects 4 parameters, one is optional; `options` and your last parameter should be a `callback function`. The signature for the callback is `callback(err)` meaning the callback function you pass should take first param to handle error if the function `writeFile` encounters error while writing. If there is no error then `err` will be `null`

Sample usage from docs:

```
fs.writeFile('message.txt', data, (err) => {
  // check if there is error
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('The file has been saved!');
});
```

In your call, the method is missing the final `callback function` parameter
`fs.writeFile("message.txt", "DUMMY" // , missing);` You can pass in your custom function as well like:

```
function writeSuccess(err) {
  // check if there is error
  if (err) console.error(err);
  else console.log('write success');
}

fs.writeFile("message.txt", "DUMMY", writeSuccess);
```

Read more about `callback` in general on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function)